# How to get total possible result set from a pagination type query?

Tags: sqlite, pagination

I'm using SQLLite in AS3 AIR, and am paginating like in the following example query (100 results per page):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE "%my keywords here%" LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

It works fine - I change the offset when the user hits a next or previous button. So the next button's subsequent query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE "%my keywords here%" LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

Just wondering if it's possible to get the total number of possible results, so I can dsiplay 'page 3 of 12' etc? Or do I have to do two queries - the first a count(*) without the LIMIT and OFFSET so I get the result total, and then the above query to get the actual page result?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite computes result records on the fly, so it is not possible to find out how many records you would have gotten without the `LIMIT`; you must use `COUNT(*)`.

Please note that the order of records is not guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY`.
Furthermore, large `OFFSET` value are very inefficient; you should continue after the last value of the curren page (see [Scrolling Cursor](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor)).

Comment: Thanks CL - the scrolling cursor page makes sense to me. Just to clarify re using COUNT(*) to get the total result set - that would have to be done as a seaparte query, right, ie no way to include it in the query that actually displays the results?

Comment: A query returns a result table with a fixed number or rows and columns; including the `COUNT(*)` is possible with enough contortions, but would not make sense.

Comment: Regarding the scrolling cursor - it only seems to work if you have a search term. What if you want to paginate using a next or previous button to just browse through an entire data set, ordered by, say title? When paging forward, what do you store as the last row viewed? I don't think you can use the row's id number, as your rows may not be in alphabetical order. Is there a way?

Comment: I should have clarified - is there a way NOT using large OFFSETs? Doing it with offset is taking up to 10 seconds to return results from a set of 180 000.

Comment: You always have *some* order (if you don't user `ORDER BY`, you get random results, and pagination does not make sense). You use the value of that column to identify the last row (or, if the column does not contain unique values, multiple columns).

Comment: I run into a problem using the last term as the reference for a search ordered by singer then title. WHERE singer='Madonna' AND title>:lasttitle doesn't return anything if the next record does not have Madonna for it's singer. Trying WHERE singer>'Madonna' AND title>:lasttitle fails if the next singer was meant to be Madonna. WHERE singer>='Madonna' AND title>:lasttitle fails to find any titles for the next due singer that are alphabetically lower than Madonna's last shown title. I would use the row ids in the query, but that fails if the next due title has an id lower than the last. CheersBTW

Comment: In this particular example, the desired result is to show *only* tracks from Madonna, ordered by title. The `singer='Madonna'` filter is not related with the pagination algorithm itself.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of SQLite (3.25.0 and later) there is support for [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html). This may not be most efficient way of doing it, but you can get total number of records in the same query as follows:

```
SELECT *, COUNT() OVER() AS totalCount  FROM dt_fi_business_account WHERE fi_name LIKE "%cre%" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Just keep in mind that the total count will be returned with every row.